# How i can grep only subdomain names without "target.com"

Tags: bash, reconnaissance, bash-scripting

i have w wordlist of subdomains contains like this :

```
admin.bugbountytarget.com
portal.bugbountytarget.com
sales.bugbountytarget.com
vpn1.bugbountytarget.com
dev.test.bugbountytarget.com
...
```

And I want to grep subdomains names without `".bugbountytarget.com"` Only:

```
admin
portal
sales
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is a question on using grep, not on information security.

Comment: `sed -e 's/.bugbountytarget.com//g' domainlist.txt`

Comment: @ThoriumBR's regex needs a trailing `$` or else it'll convert `oops.bugbountytarget.com.au` into `oops.au`. It'll also show all non-matching entries without modification, which I assume is undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

With grep specifically (assuming it is compiled with libpcre):

```
grep -Po '^.*\b(?=\.bugbountytarget\.com$)' domainlist.txt
```

This just looks for the target at the end, in a forward lookahead (not a part of the match) and then prints the match.

With awk, no regular expressions needed (faster but you'll only notice with a massive file):

```
awk 'index($0, ".bugbountytarget.com") == length($0) - 19 {
  print substr($0, 1, length($0) - 20)
}' domainlist.txt
```

This looks for a substring (the target domain), ensures it's at the end of the line, then prints it without the target. Lengths matter.

With sed:

```
sed '/\.bugbountytarget\.com$/!d; s///' domainlist.txt
```

This finds lines that end with a literal `.bugbountytarget.com` and then it substitutes that last match with an empty string and prints that out.

Comment: Or `sed -n 's/\.bugbountytarget\.com$//p' file` which is arguably idiomatic for this use

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 – Neat! My version is theoretically faster, based on some optimization I heard a looong time ago suggesting that s/// is more expensive than //.